# Use lambda functions in the build method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-build

When a widget has some logic (ex: `if`/`else`), if often see the logic being done at the beginning of the build method and stored in variables that are reused.

For example

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ... Some logic 0 here
  final result0 = // ...
  // ... Some logic 1 here
  final result1 = // ...
  // ...
  return Column(
    children: [
      // ...
      MyWidget0(
        parameter: result0,
      ),
      // ...
      MyWidget1(
        parameter: result1,
      ),
      // ...
    ],
  );
}
```

which I sometimes feel a bit hard to read as the logic of the widget `x` is at the beginning and not with the widget `x` itself.

I never see people using lambda methods like:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      // ...
      MyWidget0(
        parameter: () {
          // ... Some logic 0 here
          final result0 = // ...
          return result0;
        }(),
      ),
      // ...
      MyWidget1(
        parameter: () {
          // ... Some logic 1 here
          final result1 = // ...
          return result1;
        }(),
      ),
      // ...
    ],
  );
}
```

This allows to have the logic `x` next to the widget `x` (where it is used).

And also, if `MyWidget1` is not always built:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    // ...
    if (condition) 
      MyWidget1(
        // ...
      ),
    // ...
  ],
),
```

logic 1 won't be executed if `condition` is `false`; unlike in the first example where logic 1 is always run at the beginning of the `build` method.

---

I was wondering if there were any drawbacks to using lambda functions in the build method as illustrated.
Or if it is a bad practice, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference.  I'd expect the compiler to optimize the anonymous function usage so that both versions are equivalent.  And indeed, using [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) to examine the disassembled output, I don't see any difference between:

```dart
void main() {
  print('foo');
}
```

and

```dart
void main() {
  () { print('foo'); }();
}
```

Whether superfluous anonymous functions make `build` methods more readable is subjective. I personally think that they would usually make code (especially the surrounding code) less readable due to the extra indentation and the increased space between arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using lambda functions in `build` is a bad practice. It is just a matter of personal preference. In the example that you used, the lambda function will work perfectly. Just for readability purposes, I don't use lambda functions.

I think this is more readable than using lambda:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final isLoggedIn = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final text = isLoggedIn ? 'Welcome' : 'Login';
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

Using lambda

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final isLoggedIn = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      () {
        return isLoggedIn ? 'Welcome' : 'Login';
      } (),
    );
  }
}
```